# Calling onItemClick on each itemView instead of the same rootView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a List View with items that i want to expand on a user tapping them, and eventually I got this to work. Sort of. The problem is that no matter which item is tapped, the topmost visible item expands, instead of the one that the user has selected. It seems as though I need to call `onItemClick` on each `itemView` instead of the same `rootView`, but there doesn't seem to be any real resources describing this process.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.teamplum.projectapple.Courses">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/itemView"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:onClick="expand">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:onClick="expand">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="expand"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d40"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="expand"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telephone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d40"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="expand"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/county"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#6438"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="expand"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

relevant snippet from work.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(work.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "email","description","name","county","phone"},
                new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.description, R.id.name,R.id.county,R.id.telephone});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //itemList = findViewById(R.id.itemView);
                final LinearLayout ex;
                ex = findViewById(R.id.expandable);
                ex.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                int newHeight = ex.getMeasuredHeight() * 3;

                ValueAnimator slideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, newHeight);
                slideAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                slideAnimator.setDuration(300);
                slideAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        ex.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        ex.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                slideAnimator.start();
            }
        });


    }
```

Thank you for your time, I hope a solution is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually using any reference to the view that was clicked on. Try this.

`final LinearLayout ex = view.findViewById(R.id.expandable);`

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing with the following line, `ex = findViewById(R.id.expandable);` ? I tried your suggestion anyways, and no affect was made.

Comment: You can check the method, but I'd assume its using the activities `findViewById` which would just return the first instance it finds, which would always be the first item in your list.

Comment: you're right, `findViewById` does return the first instance it finds, but so does `view.findViewById`. This seems to be the problem. what do you suggest to use instead?

Comment: `view.findViewById` will find the `R.id.expandable` scoped to (inside) that view, not the whole activity. You'll want to set a break point in your `onItemClick` and make sure the item you've clicked on is the expected one.

Comment: Interestingly, I set breakpoints to `final LinearLayout ex = view.findViewById(R.id.expandable);`, `int newHeight = ex.getMeasuredHeight() * 3;` and `ValueAnimator slideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, newHeight);`, and none of them were activated when I tapped on an item. I'm not great with breakpoints, what could this mean?

Comment: If the action of the code appears visually but your break points aren't getting hit make sure you're in debug mode. Otherwise it means your method isn't actually be called.

Comment: But I am in debug mode, I have hit break points before and it helped me debug my code. Also, the animation is still being played and the topmost being expanded, as the code tells it to do, which makes it interesting

Comment: If you were to put a breakpoint in the activities `onCreate` does that get hit? I know sometimes the debugger can have issues with nested classes. Try kill the app and restarting with a fresh debugger.

Comment: I put two breakpoints inside the onCreate method, which both get hit as expected. What does this mean?

Comment: I'd kill the current debug process and launch a fresh one.

Comment: I tried that, no results. I closed android studio, reopened it, tried again, no results. I'm so confused.

Comment: Looks like you've got some debugging ahead of you. Setup a dummy `contactlist` and take all that code out of the async task and just run it right in the activity. See if you can then hit the break point and figure out what's going on inside `onItemClick`. Then when you get it working add back in the async task and go from there.